# Does it make sense to add a varnish in front of node GraphQL server?

Tags: express, caching, varnish, graphql

[image: actual architecture]

Here's the actual architecture, the frontend hits the graphql server directly and graphql server hits the Varnish through facebook DataLoader. Does the graphql nodejs server can handle thousands of request as is or does it make sense to add a Varnish between the front and the nodejs graphql server ?